# PHP MySQL JSON Organizing by Data

Tags: php, mysql, json

i need to be able to organize my JSON by category name. I am linking two tables together by Category ID (items) and Key (category). I want to be able to organize all the items tagged with a category ID to be organized under its category name from the category table. Here is my code so far:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM items,category WHERE items.category_id = category.key";
$result = mysql_query($query,$link) or die('Errant query:  '.$query);
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))

extract($row);
    $channel['items'][] = array(
          'title' => $title,
    'category_id' => $category_id,
    'category_name' => $category_name,
    'category_key' => $key,
    );
}   
    $channels = array($channel);
    $json = json_encode($channel);
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo $json;
}
```

Which outputs JSON like this:

```
{
"items": [
    {
        "title": "putting in title",
        "category_id": "7",
        "category_name": "Stuff 1",
        "category_key": "7"
    },
    {
        "title": "another title",
        "category_id": "7",
        "category_name": "Stuff 1",
        "category_key": "7"
    },
```

But i need for the JSON to be organized by Category name, like this:

```
{
"Stuff 1": [
    {
        "title": "putting in title",
        "category_id": "7",
        "category_name": "Stuff 1",
        "category_key": "7"
    },
    {
        "title": "another title",
        "category_id": "7",
        "category_name": "Stuff 1",
        "category_key": "7"
    },
"Stuff 2": [
    {
        "title": "putting in title",
        "category_id": "7",
        "category_name": "Stuff 2",
        "category_key": "7"
    },
    {
        "title": "another title",
        "category_id": "7",
        "category_name": "Stuff 2",
        "category_key": "7"
    },
```

Any help to accomplish this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$channel[$category_name][] = array(
      'title' => $title,
'category_id' => $category_id,
'category_name' => $category_name,
'category_key' => $key,
);
```

Comment: OMG! That was too easy! I'm embarassed. Thank you Lauri. What if i need to put everything into a items array too? How would i go about that please?

Comment: You mean `$channel['items'][$category_name]`?